# Bitwise shift and byte cast gives different results in Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, .net, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm testing the following code in both C# and Java:

```
int lngCRC = 3012;
byte[] crc = new byte[2];
crc[0] = (byte)(lngCRC & 0xFF);
crc[1] = (byte)(lngCRC >> 8);
```

C# output is:

```
crc[0] = 196;  
crc[1] = 11;
```

Java output is:

```
crc[0] = -60;  
crc[1] = 11;
```

How can I get the same result in both languages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java bytes are signed (i.e. between -128 and 127). I guess in C# they are unsigned.

3012 in binary is `00001011 11000100`.

The higer byte is 11, no matter if it's treated as a signed or unsigned byte.

When you treat the low byte - 11000100 - as an unsigned byte, it's 196

When you treat it as a signed byte, it's -60.